# What is the correct way to pass arguments to a C++ Dll from C# and back?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, pinvoke

I'm working on a C++ DLL, which should be able to receive and pass some arguments back to a C# application.

I was able to do that, which is working fine. At least i thought so. The code is working fine on my PC, but not on my colleague's PC. On his PC the same code (which is working without errors on my PC) produces not the same output, or prodces errors. So basicly it is behaving very weird.

The C++ function:

```
extern "C"
{
   __declspec( dllexport ) BOOL __stdcall MyFunction( char * StringIn, char *StringOut, BOOL bState );
}
```

And i use it this way in C#:

```
    [DllImport( @"PathToMyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall )]
    public static extern bool MyFunction( string StringToDLL, StringBuilder StringFromDLL, bool bState );

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int bufferSize = 16384;

        string StringToDLL = "This is a sample string";
        StringBuilder StringFromDLL = new StringBuilder( bufferSize );

        Console.WriteLine( "Return value      = " + MyFunction( StringToDLL, StringFromDLL, true ).ToString() );
        Console.WriteLine( "Sent to DLL       = " + StringToDLL.ToString() );
        Console.WriteLine( "Returned from DLL = " + StringFromDLL.ToString() );

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

So my questions are:
Am i doing something wrong? Or is there some settings in Visual Studio which could cause this kind of a behaviour? Also, how should i correctly allocate memory for the StringOut in C#? There is a scenario possible where the StringOut would be bigger than buffersize, but i don't know how big it would be exactly?(I would know it only inside the DLL)
Does anyone has any idee why does the same code behave itself differently on a different PC?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you allowed to convert strings declared in C# directly into char* implicitly? At one time I wrote wrappers for native C++ classes using C++/CLI (following this tutorial: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_managed/interop/article.php/c6867/Consuming-Unmanaged-C-Class-Libraries-from-NET-Clients.htm) and I had to be very careful about marshalling types between the native C++ side and the C++/CLI managed side.

Comment: @Ian Yes, you can. This is part of the P/Invoke layer.

Comment: It looks like there is nothing wrong with this code. Probably you should look for the problem elsewhere. BTW, you can omit calling convention - stdcall is default.

Comment: @Nikolay: no i can't. If i omit it, the code doesn't work. I read somewhere that the default callingconvention for C# is cdecl, not stdcall.

Comment: I think APIs like this might generally pass the length of the string?

Comment: @Derek: ok, but how do i create a new string after the function completed? I'm not familiar with c#.

Comment: I was pretty sure the default is stdcall.. Check out MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention.aspx. When you import windows dll, you normally don't specify calling convention, but all windows dlls have stdcall? So maybe it does not work for another reason if omit stdcall.. I would check memory allocation in the C++ function.

Comment: BTW, "bool" is also correct, it is marshalled by default to Int32 which is "BOOL". i.e I would bet the problem is NOT with the code you posted.

Comment: @Nikolay:i appreciate your effort, but i have no idee, why it doesn't work. I also compiled the code as a console application, and debugged it so too, but i have no clue what could be wrong. Everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: Maybe you send too much data to the output string (more than reserved in string builder)? Or the output string is not null-terminated?

Comment: I definitly pass a shorter string then reserved, and i also null terminate the string. I thought of these things too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct given the information in the question. The problem likely lies elsewhere. The obvious place to look is the unmanaged code. I suggest that you debug that.

Your code is a buffer overrun waiting to happen. How can the callee avoid overrunning the buffer if it does not know its size? Options include:

1. Passing the buffer length to the unmanaged code.
2. Using BSTR which allows for arbitrarily long strings by way of allocating off the shared COM heap.

Comment: Another option is to have a version of the DLL function that returns the maximum size of the buffer that needs to be allocated.  Then a subsequent call to the function is done with an appropriately sized buffer.  A little old-fashioned, but this is the way that a few API's work.

Comment: @Paul That's the normal way to implement option 1

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: So basicly you are saying, that i should rewrite my code, to hav an extra parameter which holds the length of the string. Then i should call it twice. For first time, it should return the length, and for the second time i should pass the correct length and only then should i return the string? Did i understand it correctly? Thanks for the idee, but this still doesn't explain thy it works on my PC. And the string i return is definitly shorter than buffersize.

Comment: The code in the question is fine. You need to do some debugging.

Comment: It should be easy enough for you to write a simple test DLL to prove the interop is fine. Then you can get on with debugging the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps, this is how I interface my C++ based DLL to C#.

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.DLL", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi,ExactSpelling=true, 
           CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int MyFunction 
(MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]StringBuilder strinIn, 
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]StringBuilder stringOut);
```

So the difference is that I specify the marshal type.

The C++ DLL (exported as 'C' function) would then have the following prototype:

```
LONG WINAPI MyFunction(const char *In, char *Out);
```

Note:  I am *not* a C# expert.  This is what I needed to do to get my C++ DLL function to be called by a C# application.

Comment: Your MarshalAs statements are pointless here. What's more you should use string for an in parameter.

Comment: Use `string` rather than `StringBuilder` for an input parameter. FWIW, the question states that the native code is C++. Of course for interop, `std::string` is not appropriate.